# "adb devices" and "lsusb" not showing device via USB-C but is showing up by USB 3 and 2

Tags: usb, adb, usb-c

My Android device is not showing up when I type `adb devices` or `lsusb` when connected via USB-C, but it does show up and works fine when using a regular USB 2 or 3 cable.

Any ideas what might be wrong and how I can fix this?

I'm using Kubuntu 19.04.

My only thoughts is the USB-C cable might not support data, but this can't be the case because it was working fine up until a week ago. I also ordered a brand new USB-C cable and that hasn't solved the problem either ! Maybe a software update has caused a problem? I tried rebooting into an earlier Kernal but that didn't solve the problem.

Also tried it with different phones. Same happens. Won't work on USB-C but will work on USB 2/3.

Comment: I've seen where front vs back USB Ports don't work the same either.....I think it's always recommended to use Port that is attached to the Mother Board for data transfer, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I have a new Spectre x360 2019, which has 2 USB-C ports and 1 USB 3 only, so I'm a bit stuck for choice. It worked last week on USB-C, but not any more.

Comment: I flashed my system with a previous BIOS version (I think there was an upgrade a week ago or so) and it seems to be working now in both Windows 10 and Kubuntu 19.04... fingers crossed it will keep working.